# Localhost not working after basic installation on WSL

Tags: php, apache, localhost, lamp, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install a LAMP working environnement but for some reason nothing happen. The lack of error messages makes me wonder what to look for.

I followed the Ubuntu installation process :

```
sudo apt install apache2 php libapache2-mod-php mysql-server php-mysql
```

At that stage, localhost should display the "It works!" message but it doesn't.

I have been restarting the apache service several times with no effect:

```
sudo service apache restart
```

it looks to be fine anyway.

I have checked the following files as advices on some online tutorial :

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

I am atually clueless on what to troubleshoot at that point.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What actually happens when you go to `localhost`? Also, are you using a stable windows version and WSL1, or are you using a insider-preview with WSL2? (With WSL2, the linux dist currently gets it's own IP-address instead of sharing Windows IP)

Comment: Chrome is showing a "ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED" error code.

I didn't try to get insider preview so I guess it's WSL1 even tough I can't find how to check which version I have.

For what it's worth I used to have a XAMPP setup with a working locahost before I decided to uninstall it.

Comment: Was localhost working before? Or you just did a new installation of WSL?
Are you able to access other services via localhost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have apache2 installed. Try running this instead:
    sudo service apache2 restart

I tried installing LAMP on WSL too. But I was lucky. I followed these steps:

Step 1: Update and Upgrade the ubuntu subsystem

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Step 2: Start bash.exe type:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

remember the caret (^) at the end of the command.

add these 2 lines in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf :

```
Servername localhost
AcceptFilter http none
```

then you can start apache :

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

Step 3: Test Web Server, PHP and MySQL
Test Apache: Open Web Browser and type this URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1 or http://localhost
```

Test PHP: Create below file (info.php) and place it in /var/www/html

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Open Web Browser and type this URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1/info.php or http://localhost/info.php
```

Test MySQL: Type below command in bash prompt

```
service mysql start
mysql -uroot -ppassword
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I haven't reinstalled with the lamp-server^ package (it didn't make sense to me as I already installed apache2 myself) but I did try that command :

/etc/init.d/apache2 start

instead of 

sudo service apache2 start

and it now seems to work. I wonder what's the difference.

Comment: I think its the same. Maybe WSL requires programs to be called differently. I don't know for sure. I'm glad it worked for you.

Comment: When I run this command:
 
`
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
`
 
I get this error:

 
`Output of config test was:
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/run/apache2': Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lock/apache2.rBfnTgPrFJ': Operation not permitted`

 
How do I fix that?